# Docker caching of .m2 doesn't work locally

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Consider this of `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
variables:
     MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=/root/.m2/repository"

cache:
     key: "M2"
     paths:
        - /root/.m2/repository
```

This works correctly when running directly in gitlab, but it doesn't work locally when running as:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker test
```

If I run it locally like this, I can see messages like `Successfully extracted cache`, but then it re-downloads all the maven dependencies, which in my case meaning downloading hundreds of megabytes.

I cannot see the difference between running it locally and remotely, both of them should work the same I guess?

Where is this cache stored? Can I somehow verify there is actually something stored?

Answer (score 1):

As in [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/15167), you need to put your m2 cache folder into a volume, or the container would start from scratch (empty cache) every time, promting maven to download *everything* all over again.

That issue also reports, instead of using volumes:

> The `cache.paths` value doesn't need to be specified if you point the repo to something in `/cache`; the version I'm actually using currently is below, and I don't see the '`Removing..`' line for `.m2`:

```
image:
  maven:3.3.9-jdk-8

variables:
  MAVEN_OPTS: -Dmaven.repo.local=/cache/maven.repository

test:
  script: "mvn test"
```

But using a volume remains the most portable solution:

> We edit our config to include a local docker host volume named `host-cache`, and we just replace `/cache` references above with `/host-cache` which doesn't depend on any undocumented runner defaults.

Comment: Well that is a different solution, but will this work also on gitlab? The mounted volume needs to exist there which it probably won't?

Comment: @Vojtěch Yes, it will work: the host folder needs to be created first (only once), but once it is created, it can be mounted as a volume.